# How to Retrieve Login Callback from twitter webview using fabric

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am implementing twitter login using fabric, the login with native app seems fine. But when i am trying the login without twitter app installed in the device, it starts authorization with the webview, but on completion i didnt receive any callback neither in onSucccess or failure method

```
           mTwitterAuthClient.authorize(ConnectSocialMedia.this, new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession> result) {
                        // Success
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                        // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
                        com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession session = result.data;
                        ApplicationData.setSharedPrefValue(mActivity, "twittertoken", session.getAuthToken().token);
                        ApplicationData.setSharedPrefValue(mActivity, "twittertokensecret", session.getAuthToken().secret);
                        ApplicationData.setSharedPrefValue(mActivity, "twitterid", String.valueOf(session.getUserId()));
                        imgTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mTwitterLoginButton.setEnabled(false);
                        btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        getTwitterCover(String.valueOf(session.getUserId()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", e);
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Twitter Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTwitterLoginButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

and neither on onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Make sure that the mTwitterLoginButton hears the result from any
    // Activity that it triggered.
    mTwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add any call back Url in your Twitter app settings page. Every thing will work correctly after that. :)